# How can I detect if an external monitor is connected (HDMI, DP, USB-C) and then start a program/workflow?

Tags: display, usb, automator, hdmi, automation

I want to launch a specific program or workflow if an external display gets connected to my MacBook (M1) in any way (HDMI, DP, USB-C).

I know there is Hazel for folder specific stuff and Automator, but I couldn't find any solution to listen for external devices being connected and then doing something.